# Mapping web service response to business object properties

Tags: .net

I have the following class in the business layer.

```
 Class Person {
    private string firstName;
    Public string FirstName
    {
       get{
                      return firstName;
                 }
       set{ 
                      firstName = value;
                 }
    }
    private string lastName;
    Public string LastName
    {
       get{
                      return lastName;
                 }
       set{
                      lastName = value;
                 }
    }
```

}

Following web service gets me the the data that need to be set in the Person object.

```
public partial class MyWebservice 
{
    private string strFstName;

    private string strLstName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string FName {
        get {
            return this.strFstName;
        }
        set {
            this.strFstName = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string LName {
        get {
            return this.strLstName;
        }
        set {
            this.strLstName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to map the response from web service to the business object.Above is just a sample. I have a business layer class with 100+ properties that needs to be populated from the web service response. I know only one method. ie. Iterate thru the web servcie response and set the business object properties. Is there an easier way to map the web service properties to the business object properties ? I'm looking for an easier way with less lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)